# Creating different instance of the same prototype in Javascript

Tags: javascript, classloader, prototypal-inheritance, static-variables

I'd like to create 2 different "instances" of the same prototype in Javascript. Please note that the word "instances" here does not refer to "instantiated classes" but 2 distinct class instances (one specific class that has been loaded from 2 different class loaders in Java terms for example).

Assuming I have this object:

```
var protoObj = {
  prop: "",
  method: function () {
    // do stuffz
  }
}

protoObj.method.staticProperty = 0;

function childObj (prop)  {
  this.prop = prop;
}
childObj.prototype = protoObj;

var child1 = new childObj("First Child");
var child2 = new childObj("Second Child");

console.log("Prop:", child1.prop); //prints "Prop: First Child"
console.log("Prop:", child2.prop); //prints "Prop1: Second Child"

child1.method.staticProperty = 1;
child2.method.staticProperty = 2;

console.log("Child1 Static:", child1.method.staticProperty); //prints "Child1 Static: 2" <-- I wanted this to be 1. I want each instance to have its own "parent"
console.log("Child2 Static:", child2.method.staticProperty); //prints "Child2 Static: 2"
```

**My goal is for `child1.method.staticProperty` to have a *different* value from `child2.method.staticProperty`**

You might ask why this is needed? Storing state in function properties is wrong indeed, but the code above comes from the Typescript compiler which compiles "Class Statics" as properties of JavaScript constructor functions. What I need is to have different static values for the same class name.

Note that in my case the `protoObj` is essentially a javascript applicationApi (a 20K line file) and our goal is to be able to create 2 distinct instances of he application while loading the library only once.

Comment: Uh, if they actually were distinct classes (created from the same code executed twice), your code would work?

Comment: PLease review updated question, I forgot to add the `.prototype` assignment

Comment: There is only one `childObj` in your code, which "class" exactly is instantiated twice?

Comment: I want `child1.method.staticProperty` to have a different value from `child2.method.staticProperty`. Right now the code doesn't do what I want it to. I want each child object to "have its own prototype object"

Comment: Then you have to create two prototype objects, not just one `protoObj`.  You say you load a class from 2 different class loaders, but don't show the code for that. If the whole class, including its prototype, would have been loaded/instantiated twice, your code would work.

Comment: Obviously I can't do that. Nor do I want to clone the first object (it is a whole library)

Comment: If you can't do that, you can't have the two objects have their own prototype objects.

Comment: You say it is "out of scope", but your [actual problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) is still unclear. And it looks like the solution you ask for doesn't exist.

Comment: @Konstantine both objects hold a reference to an instance called protoobj. It isn't actually using the prototype chain correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My goal is for `child1.method.staticProperty` to have a different value from `child2.method.staticProperty`

That is only possible when the two methods are distinct, so there are two prototype objects that your objects inherit from - which is not possible without creating two `protoObj`s or cloning it, which you said you don't want to.

> Note that in my case the `protoObj` is essentially a javascript applicationApi (a 20K line file) and our goal is to be able to create 2 distinct instances of he application

Include the script file twice to execute it twice and create two distinct objects:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="applicationApi.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    console.assert(childObj.prototype == protoObj);
    var firstInstance = childObj;
    protoObj.method.staticProperty = 1;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="applicationApi.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    console.assert(childObj.prototype == protoObj);
    var secondInstance = childObj;
    protoObj.method.staticProperty = 2;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log(new firstInstance);
    console.log(new secondInstance);
    console.log(firstInstance !== secondInstance);
</script>
```

Notice however that the need to do this suggests a fault in the design of the api library.

> …while loading the library only once.

Just send the appropriate caching headers and it'll be done implicitly.

Comment: We had this solution in mind and we're either going to go with this, or use a custom webpack plugin to modify the output file in two places in order to expose its `factory` function. Your answer does solve MY end problem, it doesn't solve the question's problem however (which I believe cannot be done in the first place)

Comment: @Konstantine Yes, should I add to the answer that it is impossible?

Comment: Yes please. There are no other answers clearly stating that so I was about to add my own.

Answer (score 0):

static property are class level property and the change in static property will be reflected to every child as same . 
As you can see in your case when you are printing the nonstatic variable the answer is correct , but when you are printing the static variable , the output is having same value. **child1, child2 are different instance but having same static

```
   protoObj.prototype.childObj = function() {
      console.log("Downloading protoObj ...");
   }
```

Try this.... When a new protoObj object is created, this new object will ‘inherit’ the childObj method from the prototype of the constructor function and becomes available for use.

Comment: As I said I know that. I want child1 and child2 to inherit from a different prototype object which I create only once however. Like loading the same class from a different class loader in java

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I don't really understand the trick here. Can you elaborate? I tried what I think you mean but nothing changed...

Comment: Not my answer, I just edited it. You're looking for @Matec009.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to instantiate the static property for each 'static instance'.

This takes advantage of javascripts dynamic nature and actually overwrites .method with an instance of itself.

You'll end up over-writing the reference to the base protoObj.method with a new instance of it for each child object. I believe this is what you're trying to ask in your question.

```
var protoObj = {
  prop: "",
  method: function () {
    // do stuffz
  }
}

protoObj.method.staticProperty = 0;

function childObj (prop)  {
  this.prop = prop;
}
childObj.prototype = protoObj;

var child1 = new childObj("First Child");
var child2 = new childObj("Second Child");
var child3 = new childObj("Third Child");

console.log("Prop:", child1.prop); //prints "Prop: First Child"
console.log("Prop:", child2.prop); //prints "Prop: Second Child"
console.log("Prop:", child3.prop); //prints "Prop: Second Child"

child1.method = new child1.method();
child1.method.staticProperty = 1;
child2.method = new child2.method();
child2.method.staticProperty = 2;

console.log("Child1 Static:", child1.method.staticProperty); //prints "Child1 Static: 2" <-- I wanted this to be 1. I want each instance to have its own "parent"
console.log("Child2 Static:", child2.method.staticProperty);
console.log("Child3 Static:", child3.method.staticProperty);
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to create a new instance of `method` every time in the constructor. Basically to move `method` out of the prototype and into the constructor:

```
var protoObj = {
  // some share stuff
}

function childObj (prop)  {
  // non-shared stuff:
  this.prop = prop;
  this.method = function () {
    // do stuffz
  }
  this.method.staticProperty = 0;
}

childObj.prototype = protoObj;
```

My personal rules of putting what things where: if a property is a string or number or boolean then put it in the prototype, everything else put it in the constructor. This is because the prototype is inherited by shallow copy. It does not have to be functions, you'll get in trouble if you have objects in your prototype:

```
function Foo () {}
Foo.prototype = {
  a: "no problem",
  b: {
    x: "problem"
  }
}

var i = new Foo();
var j = new Foo();
var k = new Foo();

i.a += " 1";
j.a += " 2";
k.a += " 3";

console.log(i.a , j.a , k.a); // no problem 1, 2, 3

i.b.x += " 1";
j.b.x += " 2";
k.b = { x: "problem 3" };

console.log(i.b.x , j.b.x , k.b.x); // problem 2, 2, 3
```

If you follow the rule to only use prototypes for properties of strings, numbers and booleans you won't get in trouble:

```
function Foo () {
  this.b = {
    x: "no problem"
  };
}
Foo.prototype = {
  a: "no problem"
}

i.b.x += " 1";
j.b.x += " 2";
k.b = { x: "no problem 3" };

console.log(i.b.x , j.b.x , k.b.x); // no problem 1, 2, 3
```

Comment: I think I get what you mean, but in my case `protoObj` comes defined with all the properties and methods that we need and we can't move or recreate them in each instance. That's why I was looking for a "loading 2 distinct versions of the same prototype" type of solution.

Comment: @Konstantine: Unfortunately there is no other solution for that. What you can do is leave `method` in prototype but not use it: instead replace `method` each instance. I'd be against not deleting `method` from prototype because it is misleading - it does absolutely nothing and will be replaced in the constructor. If you are lucky and `method` does not use `this` you can replace `method` outside the constructor by reassigning a new function to it for each instance. Again that means the `method` in the prototype is misleading and useless